# Add customer rule in .htaccess automatically with php

Tags: php, apache

I'm working on the website and after I submit something in the website php bring me some URL like this: 
www.example.com/***text***
and I make this URL with **mod_rewrite** apache and the orginal file is 
www.example.com/file.php?number=***text***
I add this rule manually:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^ABC$ file.php?number=ABC
RewriteRule ^DEF$ file.php?number=DEF
```

But I want to php add these rule to the .htaccess automatically when user submit something.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ file.php?number=$1 [L,QSA]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I don't understand that , what is %{REQUEST_FILENAME} or !-f ? How can I use this in php?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means rewrite if it is not a file and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means rewrite if it is not a directory. This is `mod_rewrite` syntax not for PHP code.

Comment: Tnx, But I want to use it in php and I don't have any knowlage about apache

Comment: What you posted in question is mod_rewrite rule. You can just copy paste these rules in your root .htaccess or just delete the question if you don't want .htaccess solution.

Comment: I write in my question title "automatically with php"

Comment: You tagged your question with `.htaccess` and showed rewrite rules too :)